# does anybody know how to de-expand the c drive on windows 10?

Tags: windows

I installed a 1tb ssd on my computer & I expanded the c drive to use the drive but Now I want to install linux on the d: drive so I need to de-expand it. it seems odd & that's fair

I have no idea & tried nothing I am not an expert in this I mostly just expanded it for disk useage but now I don't know what to do